# How to differentiate a Div from rest of the div on same row having same look and feel ? border/shade etc?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, web, human-interface-guideline

[image: four boxes showing different type of results]

I'm working on a web application where I have 4 result types of a data and I'm showing all four on the page in same row with same look & feel of divs (can be seen in picture). The Box_D result is calculated using different techniques so I want to show it slightly different from rest of the results (i.e. from Box_A , Box_B & Box_C) but I don't want to change the look and feel of the Box_D. 
What will be the best approach to design the div such a way which makes user think its somehow different from other results. I have options of adding a lighter shadow, Border , or making the div smaller/bigger than the rest. Which approach will be the best according to user experience perspective? 
I'll be thankful for your valuable suggesstions.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply separate it a little bit from the group and put a subtle divider in between. White space is a powerful tool for grouping.

[image]

Comment: Thank you DasBeasto for your suggesstion..Its really a good idea. +1

Answer (score -2):

You want to create a class for all divs.

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

but for the last div, create an id.

```
<div class="box" id="rightbox"></div>
```

then style them via css

```
    .box {
//Your styles
}

        #rightbox {
// your unique styles for the right box
    }
```

Make sure that you mark conflicting styles as !important in the #rightbox stylings. e.g if you add a different border style.

Comment: I think the question is asking about what's a good way to let users know visually the data in Box D is different than that of the other boxes and not how to implement styling.

Comment: Kindly read the question again. I'm not asking about code or ways to implement styling for divs.